# DateTime Format in SOQL

Tags: soql

```
[SELECT Id,(SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments, OriginalActorId, ActorId, CreatedDate, Actor.Name, OriginalActor.Name FROM Steps ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) FROM ProcessInstance 
WHERE targetObjectId = :caseId
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]
```

The problem is it is giving out 2015-01-08T07:11:17.000+0000
I Just need 2015-01-08 1/8/2016 11:00 am” i.e “mm/dd/yyyy “ and 12 hour format time

Answer (score 4):

You have some options. First you can use [Date Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm). It allow you to group the data by date periods using functions like `CALENDAR_YEAR`:

```
SELECT CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)
From Account
Group By CALENDAR_YEAR(CreatedDate)
```

If you use apex you can use methods of the [Datetime Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) like `format()`:

```
Datetime myDT = Datetime.now();
String myDate = myDT.format('MM/dd/yyyy');
```